# Cleaning up data where it repeats daily

Tags: mysql

I have provided an example of how my data looks.  The table is filled with customerid balances that are negative.  Everyday a report is generated with any customerid carrying a negative balance. The report is imported into my table with a new reportdate.  Is there a way for me to achieve the following:

Return rows on the first date that the customerID reaches their maximum ending_amount found.  Meaning if a customerid reaches an ending_amount of -3.50 on day 10 of 20 days of data, I would like it to return the row of data on day 10 of 20 only and ignore the other 19 days of data associated with that customerid.

**Notes:**

**-**Customerid is a unique value.

**-**when starting_amount <> ending_amount, it indicates a change has taken place regarding that account balance.

Is there anyway I can achieve my goal by either cleaning up this table some how or by writing a query?

Thank you for your help.

```
Expected Data output

reportdate customerid starting_amount ending_amount
  1/1/17       2           -0.00          -0.50
  1/3/17       3           -0.50          -1.00
  1/4/17       1           -0.50          -3.27
  1/4/17       4           -0.00          -0.50
  1/4/17       5           -0.50          -1.32
```

Sample data

```
 tbl_accountchange

 reportdate  customerid  starting_amount ending_amount
    1/1/17     1             -0.00           -0.50
    1/1/17     2             -0.00           -0.50
    1/2/17     1             -0.50           -0.50
    1/2/17     2             -0.50           -0.50
    1/2/17     3             -0.00           -0.50
    1/3/17     1             -0.50           -0.50
    1/3/17     2             -0.50           -0.50
    1/3/17     3             -0.50           -1.00
    1/3/17     4             -0.00           -0.50
    1/3/17     5             -0.00           -0.50
    1/4/17     1             -0.50           -3.27
    1/4/17     2             -0.50           -0.50
    1/4/17     3             -1.00           -1.00
    1/4/17     4             -0.50           -0.50
    1/4/17     5             -0.50           -1.32
```

Comment: So in your data sample what would be the expected output?

Comment: Hello, I have added in my desired output.  Essentially I want to return each row on the first reportdate that the account reached its maximum ending balance found within the table.  A customerID should not be returned more than once.

Answer (score 0):

To find the maximum ending amount for each customer:

```
select customerId, max(ending_amount) max_ea
from tbl_accountchange
where reportdate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-20'
group by 1
```

To find the earliest date this value occurred for each customer:

```
select a.customerId, min(reportdate) rd
from tbl_accountchange a
join (
    -- above query
) b on a.customerId = b.customerId
    and a.ending_amount = max_ea
group by 1
```

The whole query:

```
select t.*
from tbl_accountchange t
join (select a.customerId, min(reportdate) rd
    from tbl_accountchange a
    join (
        select customerId, max(ending_amount) max_ea
        from tbl_accountchange
        where reportdate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-20'
        group by 1
    ) b on a.customerId = b.customerId
    and a.ending_amount = max_ea
    where reportdate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-20') c
    on t.customerId = c.customerId
    and t.reportdate = c.reportdate
```

None of the queries are correlated, so it should perform pretty well even for large datasets.

Note that the date range condition must be in both subqueries.

Comment: I added another parantheses before aliasing the table as c.  The response I receive is column customerid in field list is ambiguous?

Comment: @EdwardKo when you get such an error, you need to qualify which table the column you're selecting comes from. In this case, I fixed it by adding `a.` before the column name - see edited answer. Adding parenthesis shouldn't be necessary. (BTW I thumbed this query in on the bus so was likely to miss a small detail like this)